# Is there a method for building Kline trading data using live ticker information from an exchanges' API?

Tags: python, cryptography, stock, binance, kucoin

I have built a Python spot trading bot and intend to use it with KuCoin exchange. The bot requires historical OHLCV data for each coin on a 5m interval for the last 50 datapoints. My intention is retrieve this kline (candlestick) data for each coin (~1000 coins on the exchange) as fast as possible and preferably within a 5 minute window for adequate trading.

The API provides a client method for retrieving kline data, my current implementation, however it heavily restricts the frequency of this request. Setting a sleep time of 2 seconds will still yield a frequency violation. Furthermore, there is a note within the documentation that reads as follows:

> Klines should not be polled frequently. If you need real-time
> information, use the trade and book endpoints along with the websocket
> feed.

The code below is my current implementation:

```
#Import Modules
import os
import pickle
import datetime as dt
import time
import threading
import random
from kucoin.client import Market

def get_symbols():
    
    """
        This function retrieves all tradable symbols from
        the exchange.
        
        Parameters:
        -----------
        None
        
        Returns:
        -----------
        symbols: list(str)
            list of trading symbols
        
    """
    
    #Get list of possible symbols
    all_symbols = client.get_symbol_list()
    
    #For all tickers
    symbols = []
    for ticker in all_symbols:
        
        #Pull data
        symbol = ticker["symbol"]
        trading = ticker["enableTrading"]
        
        #keep if trading allowed
        if trading:
            symbols.append(symbol)
        
    return symbols

def update_kline(symbol,source_dict):
    
    #Points to pull
    DATA_PTS = 50
    
    #Get kline data
    klines = client.get_kline(symbol,'5min')
    klines = klines[:DATA_PTS]
    
    #Get the lastest epoch time from kline dataset
    latest_time = int(klines[0][0])
    
    #If kline data is not recent (info is bugged), skip
    if abs(end-latest_time) > 5*60:
        return
    
    #Make sure data has 50 full datapoints
    if len(klines) == DATA_PTS:
        source_dict[symbol] = klines    
  
def update_klines(source_dict,symbols):
    
    """
        This function continously updates kline data
        for all given symbols to a destination dictionary
        "source_dict".
        
        Parameters:
        -----------
        source_dict: dict
            where keys are symbol names and value is
            kline 2D array/list data
            
        symbols: list(str)
            symbols to pull data from
            
        Returns:
        -----------
        None
        
    """
    
    #Forever
    while True:
        
        #For each symbol
        for i,symbol in enumerate(symbols):

            #Update dictionary with kline data for symbol
            update_kline(symbol,source_dict)
            
            #Sleep for some time to avoid IP freeze
            time.sleep(random.uniform(2,3))

def main():
    
    """
        Main function to run bot.
        
        Parameters:
        -----------
        None
        
        Returns:
        -----------
        None
        
    """
    
    #Initialize client
    client = Market(url='https://api.kucoin.com')
    
    #Get symbols
    symbols = get_symbols()
    
    #Source dict which will hold kline data
    source_dict = {}
    
    #Set thread to continuously update kline data
    t = threading.Thread(target = update_klines,args=(source_dict,symbols))
    t.start()
    
#Run main function in script
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The above execution will eventually yield a return error code indicating there are too many requests. The first viable solution I can think of is to manually build the kline data using a different method. The API mentions using book and trade endpoints with websockets (not familiar with websockets). However, I am not familiar with how a kline data frame could be assembled using such data.

The second potential solution I can think of is to use an alternate exchange's API, such as Binance or even data from the yfinance library which could have less stringent kline frequency limitations. However I imagine the kline data will be somewhat different than the exchange I intend to trade on (KuCoin) and thus be problematic. However I am using the historical kline data to predict buy-in candidates. Therefore, this solution would involve using a different API/library to acquire frequent kline data and once a viable candidate is found for a buy-opportunity, request the single kline data for the symbol of interest from KuCoin to confirm its candidacy. This, as you can imagine, will have accuracy and delay drawbacks.

**KuCoin Official API Reference:**
https://docs.kucoin.com/#market-data

**KuCoin Python API Reference:**
https://github.com/Kucoin/kucoin-python-sdk

Comment: There is only one solution for your issue in practice: websocket.

Comment: @halfelf thanks for the reply. can you please consider voting on this question (as well as any other questions I have posted). I have been in a question ban for years now and it has been atrociously difficult to resolve (even having edited my past questions for clarity)